# OpenCV: Using cvGoodFeaturesToTrack with C++ mat variable

Tags: c++, opencv, vision

I am trying to use the `cvGoodFeatureToTrack` function in Visual Studio 2010 with the image type as `Mat`. Most of the examples I have seen use the `IplImage` pointer.
Right now I have this:

```
int w, h; // video frame size

Mat grayFrame;
Mat eigImage;
Mat tempImage;
const int MAX_CORNERS = 10;
CvPoint2D32f corners[MAX_CORNERS] = {0};
int corner_count = MAX_CORNERS;
double quality_level = 0.1;
double min_distance = 10;
int eig_block_size = 3;
int use_harris = false;

w = CurrFrame.size().width;
h = CurrFrame.size().height;
cvtColor(CurrFrame, grayFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvGoodFeaturesToTrack(&grayFrame,
                      &eigImage,
                      &tempImage,
                      corners,
                      &corner_count,
                      quality_level,
                      min_distance,
                      NULL,
                      eig_block_size,
                      use_harris);
```

It compiles but gives me a memory access violation. Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a starting point, if using C++ anyway (like your use of `cv::Mat` and `cv::cvtColor` suggests), then why not use C++ interface for the rest, too?

This would mean the use of [`cv::goodFeaturesToTrack`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#void%20goodFeaturesToTrack%28InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20corners,%20int%20maxCorners,%20double%20qualityLevel,%20double%20minDistance,%20InputArray%20mask,%20int%20blockSize,%20bool%20useHarrisDetector,%20double%20k%29) or a [`cv::GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#goodfeaturestotrackdetector), which are made to work on `cv::Mat` and friends instead of making unneccessary casts from `cv::Mat` to `IplImage*`.

```
cv::Mat grayFrame;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
double quality_level = 0.1;
double min_distance = 10;
int eig_block_size = 3;
int use_harris = false;

const int MAX_CORNERS = 10;
cv::cvtColor(CurrFrame, grayFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(grayFrame,
                        corners,
                        MAX_CORNERS,
                        quality_level,
                        min_distance,
                        cv::noArray(), 
                        eig_block_size,
                        use_harris);
```

Comment: Thanks. That works out. I was using the goodFeaturesToTrack function with NULL instead of the noArray(). But Your answer solved my problem.