# ARKit Perspective Correction

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, perspectivecamera, arkit

I'm working on a project with `ARKit` and I'm trying to do a perspective correction of the `ARFrame.capturedImage` to orient a piece of paper sitting on a detected plane so I can feed that into a `CoreML` model which expects images to be taken from directly overhead.

`ARKit` gives me the device orientation relative to the plane (`ARCamera.transform`, `ARCamera.eulerAngles`, and `ARCamera.projectionMatrix` all look promising).

So I have the orientation of the camera (and I know the plane is horizontal since that's all `ARKit` detects right now).. but I can't quite figure out how to create a `GLKMatrix4` that will perform the correct perspective correction.

Originally I thought it would be as easy as transforming by the inverse of `ARCamera.projectionMatrix` but that doesn't appear to work at all; I'm not entirely sure what that matrix is describing.. it doesn't seem to change much based on the device orientation.

I've tried creating my own matrix using `GLKMatrix4Rotate` and the roll/pitch/yaw but that didn't work.. I couldn't even get it working with a single axis of rotation.

I found `GLKMatrix4MakePerspective`, `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho`, and `GLKMatrix4MakeFrustum` which seem to do perspective transforms but I can't figure out how to take the information I have and translate it to the inputs of those functions to make the proper perspective transformation.

*Edit:*
As an example to better explain what I'm trying to do, I used the `Perspective Warp` tool in Photoshop to transform an example image; what I want to know is how to come up with a matrix that will perform a similar transform given the info I have about the scene.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [iOS11 `Vision`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision)'s Rectangle Detection and then feeding it into [Core Image's `CIPerspectiveCorrection` filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveCorrection).

Comment: Were you able to transform without crop using `CIPerspectiveCorrection`? Would you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using OpenCV perspective transformation. (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html,https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform)

If you're able to get the corners of your paper in the scene (for example with an `ARReferenceImage` and project them in 2D), take them. Otherwise you can try to detect the corners through OpenCV directly (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12636153/9298773) from the `UIImage` taken from `sceneView.snapshot()` with `sceneView` of type `ARSceneView`. In this last case I'd suggest you to binarize first and to change the `MAX_CORNERS` variable in the snippet at the link above to 4 (the 4 corners of your paper).

Then create a new `cv::Mat` with width and height of your choice **respecting the proportion width and height of your paper** and do perspective transform. For a guideline of this last paragraph, take a look at the section "Perspective Correction using Homography" at this link: https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/#download. **Succintly**: you ask opencv to find an appropriate transform to project your prospected paper points into a perfectly rectangular plane (your new `cv::Mat`)